# How to change color of marker in Google Map?

Tags: google-maps

I won't use  GIcon to change for the marker.Any other ways to change color of marker???

Comment: See my simple answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61507574/11208147

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope, if you wan't to customize your marker, you will need to use [GIcon](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GIcon).

You can find a whole lot of free markers at the [Google Maps Icons Project](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-icons/). The code to use a custom marker is pretty straightforward:

```
// Create our "tiny" marker icon
var blueIcon = new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON);
blueIcon.image = "http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markers/blue/blank.png";

// Set up our GMarkerOptions object
markerOptions = { icon:blueIcon };

// add the markerOptions as the second param to GMarker constructor
map.addOverlay(new GMarker(latlng, markerOptions));
```

Answer (score 4):

The "Google map icons" website moved from http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-icons/ to http://mapicons.nicolasmollet.com

There you will find 600 markers and you even have a color picker to create the icons in the color you want.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple to change marker color or shape in your saved map. Simply click on the marker. when the box opens up, click on the marker again in the box. This gives you a drop down menu of colors and shapes. Good luck!