# How to set custom marker color?

Tags: google-maps

I am building a path, by using the Google Maps API (v3), with a DirectionsRenderer and a set of waypoints.

```
       var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
         markerOptions: {
           flat: false,
           clickable: false
         },
         polylineOptions: {
           strokeColor: "#1d6db1",
           strokeOpacity: 0.8
         }
       });
```

I would like to change the default color of the markers from green, to #1d6db1, just like I did for the polyline. The thing is that there's no such option for the [markerOptions](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MarkerOptions) class. I've found one [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095574/google-maps-api-3-custom-marker-color-for-default-dot-marker), but at the same time I want to keep the A, B, C, etc. labels of my markers, which is not possible there.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Charts API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/gallery/dynamic_icons.html#pins) to generate markers.
Unfortunately it's not possible to use the `DirectionsRenderer` and have custom, lettered (or numbered) markers. You'll need to replicate the functionality of `DirectionsRenderer`.