# Dynamically Change Color of GoogleMap Icon/Marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, java-8

I am trying to change the color of a marker/icon with GoogleMaps API V3 based on user input. I can hard code the color or image link I want into the Javascript, but if I try to pass the color or link as a string variable from my Java program then it either does not show up or defaults to a red marker.

I've looked at all the following threads and at the google API:

- [Google Maps API 3 - Custom marker color for default (dot) marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095574/google-maps-api-3-custom-marker-color-for-default-dot-marker?lq=1)
- [How do I change icon colour in Google Maps API V3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206195/how-do-i-change-icon-colour-in-google-maps-api-v3?lq=1)
- [Google Maps API 3 - Custom marker color for default (dot) marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095574/google-maps-api-3-custom-marker-color-for-default-dot-marker/7686977#7686977)
- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers

All of which have either the link to the marker icon they want to use or the color HEX code already hard coded into the javascript.

My attempt, where address1 and color1 are both strings that are passed to the javascript from my Java code. color1's string, for example could be

"http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld•|4D8080":

```
function codeAddress(address1, color1){
var pinColor = color1;
address=address1;
document.geocoder.geocode( {'address': address1}, function(results, status) {
  app.callFromJavascript(address1);
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        document.map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        document.map.setZoom(13);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            icon:  pinColor,
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            map: document.map
                });
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
}
```

This results in the map centering on the location and showing the default red marker. 
If I change the string passed to color1 to be "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow-dot.png"  then no marker shows up at all.

What am I missing that I can't get these to generate from passed variables? Is it simply not possible and mandatory that the location markers be hard coded?

Comment: Can you provide Jsfiddle please

Comment: I can do a combo Java/HTML/Javascript through Jsfiddle? I'm looking at it now and it doesn't appear that I can. This is a fairly large project that involves databases and geocoding purchased zipcodes and all I want to do is know if I can pass the URL that the icon option for the marker variable as a string.

Comment: Ok but something wrong. You can change colors from variables. http://jsfiddle.net/2Vz6m/31/

Comment: @user3388636 Ahha! Thanks you made the quarter drop, I was just missing another set of single quotes when I was passing it to the javascript! Works perfectly now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works fine for me :

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow-dot.png"),
        position: results[0].geometry.location,
        map: document.map
            });
```

they do not have to be hard coded , but you do have to use the object type of `MarkerImage` to pass the url to.

You can not just pass a hex color and expect the maps API to make a new marker based on the color you just picked.  What is usually done is to like to an image url that already exists for each color that you plan to use.  Then use the code the way I showed you.

Comment: Yes, I know this works. However, this is not what I want to do. I want to select a color and pass the HEX code to javascript and have it show up as that certain color.

Comment: see my update , you are going to have to have a URL for each color that you plan on using

Comment: Okay, I have a url, say this: "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld•|4D8080" and I am passing it as a variable, in this case pinColor to the icon field for the marker. What I am trying to determine is if I can pass that URL as a variable or not.

Comment: if its a valid url - you have some weird characters in there... but anyways , yes ANY valid URL can be passed through my code here

Comment: MarkerImage is deprecated.  It has been replaced by the anonymous [google.maps.Icon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon) ([from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#icons): `Until version 3.10 of the Google Maps JavaScript API, complex icons were defined as MarkerImage objects. The Icon object literal was added in version 3.10, and replaces MarkerImage from version 3.11 onwards.`)

Comment: @geocodezip - had no idea, I'll probably go update on of m sites that uses the maps API , why don't you submit another answer explaining that?

Answer (score 2):

So if you have a hex code already with you and you have an icon obj which looks like this

```
let carIcon = {
    path: carsvg,
    scale: 0.7,
    strokeColor: 'white',
    strokeWeight: 0.10,
    fillOpacity: 1,
    fillColor: '#404040',
    offset: '2%',
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 25) // orig 10,50 back of car, 10,0 front of car, 10,25 center of car
};
```

and a marker object like this

```
let carmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: carLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: "Car",
    icon: carIcon,
    setMap: map
});
```

and say you want to change the color of the icon. To do that, simply use

`carIcon.fillColor = '#008000';`
`carmarker.setIcon(carIcon);`

This should make it to the color hex code you have. Hope it helps. Also, the icon should be SVG in this case for the color to change to take place.