# Google maps v3 default marker path with other colors

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, colors, google-maps-markers

My goal is to change the color of the nice looking default google maps marker. Therefore, I'm looking for the path / shape of the default (red) one. I've found this to change to color:

```
function pinSymbol(color) {
    return {
        path: '???' 
        fillColor: color,
        fillOpacity: 1,
        strokeColor: '#000',
        strokeWeight: 2,
        scale: 1
    };
}
```

So, by invoking the function, I would like to change the color (e.g. icon: pinSymbol("#666"). However, I don't know where to find the path? I'm not looking for the v2 / plain marker!

[image: New marker]

// edit: I've found this path:

```
path: 'M 0,0 C -2,-20 -10,-22 -10,-30 A 10,10 0 1,1 10,-30 C 10,-22 2,-20 0,0 z M -2,-30 a 2,2 0 1,1 4,0 2,2 0 1,1 -4,0',
```

(from an answer to the question: [Google Maps API 3 - Custom marker color for default (dot) marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095574/google-maps-api-3-custom-marker-color-for-default-dot-marker))

How to generate the smooth gradient?

Comment: It looks like you just can't... Had the same issue, so I had to compromise and use an ugly marker

Answer (score 5):

Using the path you provided in your question:

```
function pinSymbol(color) {
    return {
        path: 'M 0,0 C -2,-20 -10,-22 -10,-30 A 10,10 0 1,1 10,-30 C 10,-22 2,-20 0,0 z',
        fillColor: color,
        fillOpacity: 1,
        strokeColor: '#000',
        strokeWeight: 1,
        scale: 1
    };
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/s3db77ff/297/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function pinSymbol(color) {
  return {
    path: 'M 0,0 C -2,-20 -10,-22 -10,-30 A 10,10 0 1,1 10,-30 C 10,-22 2,-20 0,0 z',
    fillColor: color,
    fillOpacity: 1,
    strokeColor: '#000',
    strokeWeight: 1,
    scale: 1
  };
}
function initialize() {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(47.605, -122.333);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: latlng,
    icon: pinSymbol('red')
  });

  var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(47.5, -122.0),
    icon: pinSymbol('green')
  });
  var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6, -122.2),
    icon: pinSymbol('orange')
  });
  var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(47.7, -122.1),
    icon: pinSymbol('yellow')
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:750px; height:450px; border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
<div id="content_window"></div>
```

Comment: **Important** While this works well, the usage of paths for icons is quite demanding for the Google API and will make the rendering of the markers quite slow.

Answer (score 3):

By inspecting the Maps' code in action, I've found that in Google Maps JS API V3 the default URL of the marker is https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/spotlight-poi.png , and the marker itself is a 22x40 PNG file. To recolor it, you'd have to probably use CSS filters/JS etc. or manually re-hue it in raster graphics editor.

[image: map marker PNG]

Answer (score -1):

I think you can change the icon by doing this `marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png')`

Or you can refer to the [customize marker image documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#simple_icons).

Also, you can use the [predefined symbols](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/symbols#predefined) for your path.
Sample code:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    id: "some-id",
    icon: {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
        strokeColor: "red",
        scale: 3
    },
    map: map,
    title: "some-title",
    position: myLatlng
});
```

Comment: He probably knows he can, and he specifically asks for the path of the default marker.