# Different google marker for different pages

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am trying to implement google maps into my page but need different pins on different pages depending on the page style. Is it possible to dynamically generate a marker(marker-blue.png, marker-red.png etc.) depeding on the `<body class="bluetheme">` every time a new page loads?

```
  var myMarkers = 'images/';
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      icon: myMarkers + 'marker-blue.png',
      map: map
  });


  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems like you want to present a marker with an icon depending on the `<body>` tag, so for example if the class of the body is `<body class="purple">` a purple marker should appear on the map.

I will try to cut the code in 3 parts.

**First**

```
var array = ['blue','red','yellow',"purple","green"], //array of random colors
    random = array[Math.floor(Math.random()* array.length)]; //get some random color
 console.log("the random color to the body tag will be: " + random)
 document.getElementById('test').className = random //apply some class name
```

Here we are creating an array which values will be static colors, and we are using the [Math.floor](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_floor.asp) math method to take 1 string (color) of the array and put it like a class on the  tag.

**Second**

```
function initialize() { //simple map initialization
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ //create the marker
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!',
      icon:"http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/" +random+ "-dot.png", //taking the random variable.
  });
}
```

Here we are just taking that random variable and concat into the icon value on the icon field(take the icon links from [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095574/google-maps-api-3-custom-marker-color-for-default-dot-marker)).

**Third**

```
var test = document.getElementById('test').className; //get the actual classname of the body
console.log("the curren background color of the body is: " + test)
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);//init the map
```

Here we init the map, and also for testing-demo purposes we are printing the value of the class name.

Here is the working [JSFillde](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrjoxn43/3/), inspect the console and check the console to see how it works.

Comment: Hey thanks, but could you use something more dynamic like a  i.e.   `switch (ClassName) {
            case "bluetheme":
                icon = "blue";
                break; `    Sorry I am not very good at javascript so just improvising.

Comment: Also, where does "firstPage" come from? Should it not be "divToCheck?"

Comment: I just pasted it on.[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrjoxn43/) to make it more readable

Comment: Hey, thanks for your detailed response. I am getting the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of null` error when implementing it with my own page. I don't know if it is anything to do with the fact I am serving my own images: `icon:"_assets/img/pin-" +random+ ".png"`. Also is there a way that I can set the class on the test container rather than randomly generate it? Thanks

Comment: I have even tried the following `var  myMarkers = '../images/pin-;` (naming convention pin-blue.png). Then icon:  `myMarkers + document.getElementById('HereYoGo').className + '.png',` My HTML `<div id="HereYoGo" class="hhhg">
        <div id="map-canvas">
        </div></div>` And I still get the same erro, it does not seem to find the HereYoGo ID...

Comment: Hi thanks. I still think it is too complex for what I need to do. The container div aka body in your example is already preset on the page template so it does not need to be randomly generated. It would be something along the lines of passing a variable like this : `var colorScheme = document.getElementById('test').className; ` to the markermaker.

Comment: I also noticed an issue, when I try to run the source of your mapcode it creates a `var VanillaRunOnDomReady = function() {` with a bunch of extra code and whenever I remove it (only use the JS code from the fiddle window) I get this **Cannot set property classname** error. Is there a way of making the code more compact?

Comment: Hey, I modified the code to do what I need: Hey, [link] (http://codepen.io/Itagiba/pen/zGOzZL), my only problem now is that the map options for street view and zoom do not seem to be working but I think that this is a question for another topic. Thanks for your help.