# Change the color of one of the pin on google map in PHP

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-markers

My code is as below `

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = [
      ['add1', lat1, long1],
      ['add2', lat2, long2],
      ['add3', lat3, long3],

    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom:10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(18.528771, 73.906314),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP


    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
</script>`
```

More than one pins are there on map, I would like to display one of the pin in diff color or display an image instead of bubble.
I am implementing the code in PHP.

Comment: Can you inspect the element in firebug / chrome, and then target the class of the pin. Then set some style rules to override it?

Comment: [google-maps-api-3-custom-marker-color-for-default-dot-marker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095574/google-maps-api-3-custom-marker-color-for-default-dot-marker)

Comment: I tried to inspect but its not inspecting appropriate bubble.

Answer (score 2):

You need add an icon attribute to the marker options and set the image to the correct google pin:

```
  var image = 'images/beachflag.png';
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.890542, 151.274856);
  var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: myLatLng,
     map: map,
     icon: image
});
```

see google doc [google example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-simple)

Comment: If you think this is useful and you can please rate me.

Comment: Thanks You :) @ scaisEdge