# Google Marker : Icon is invisible

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When i try to give my google maps markers a other colour by giving them a icon the markers are invisble on my map. The fault is not that my application can't find the image. I got my icon image from

http://www.benjaminkeen.com/google-maps-coloured-markers/

My code is :

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: {
                                    lat: parseFloat(array[i].lat),
                                    lng: parseFloat(array[i].lng)
                                },
                                map: map,
                                icon: 'green_MarkerE.png'
                            });
```

Can't figure out why maps doesn't show it. When i delete my "icon: 'green_MarkerE.png'" than it works fine..

Comment: Your file path would suggest that your market icon is in the same folder as your javascript file. Is this the case?

Comment: I've always used full URL's for markers - can you try that

Comment: thx, It works. I used this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095574/google-maps-api-3-custom-marker-color-for-default-dot-marker/7686977#7686977