# How to make different color markers in cluster

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I am following the marker cluster example in leaflet which is below:
[marker-cluster](http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.markercluster/example/marker-clustering-realworld.388.html)
As shown all the markers are clustered and now I want to modify the color of the marker for some.  So i will be having another column in the file like below:

```
var addressPoints = [
[-37.8210922667, 175.2209316333, "2",0],
[-37.8210819833, 175.2213903167, "3",1],
[-37.8210881833, 175.2215004833, "3A",1],
[-37.8211946833, 175.2213655333, "1",0],
[-37.8209458667, 175.2214051333, "5",0],
[-37.8208292333, 175.2214374833, "7",1],
]
```

where 0 are blue markers and red 1 are red markers. So how can I change the color of the marker depending on the third column in the marker cluster?
**Update**

I added the following code

```
var map = L.map('map', {center: latlng, zoom: 13, layers: [tiles]});
var greenIcon = new L.Icon({
  iconUrl: '/img/marker-icon-2x-green.png',
  shadowUrl: '/img/marker-shadow.png',
  iconSize: [25, 41],
  iconAnchor: [12, 41],
  popupAnchor: [1, -34],
  shadowSize: [41, 41]
});



        var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();

        for (var i = 0; i < addressPoints.length; i++) {
            var a = addressPoints[i];
            var title = a[2];
if(a[3]==0){

var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]), { title: title },{icon: greenIcon});
}
else{

var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]), { title: title });

}

            marker.bindPopup(title);
            markers.addLayer(marker);
        }
        map.addLayer(markers);
```

But still the marker color is blue and did not change to green.Any help is appreciated

Comment: If I am not worng the above question is on the color of marker cluster where my question is not on the color of marker cluster but the individual marker itself. Correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: Hi no I think you're right. Here's a great post on updating markers, should apply I think to markers in a cluster or not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095574/google-maps-api-3-custom-marker-color-for-default-dot-marker

Comment: I updated my question I followed this [tutorial](https://github.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers) But did not worked as expected.Could you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this made the trick:

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets')
        .setView([-37.82, 175.215], 14);

    var markers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();

    for (var i = 0; i < addressPoints.length; i++) {
        var a = addressPoints[i];
        var title = a[2];

        if(a[3]==1){
var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]), {
            icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({'marker-symbol': 'car', 'marker-color': '#00FFFF'}),
            title: title
        });
        }
        else{
            var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]), {
            icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({'marker-symbol': 'car', 'marker-color': '#ff0000'}),
            title: title
        });
        }

        marker.bindPopup(title);
        markers.addLayer(marker);
    }



    map.addLayer(markers);
```

Hope it helps anyone