# Dynamic map marker icons with new Google Chart API?

Tags: javascript, api, dynamic, charts, marker

Since years I created Google dynamic map markers in Javascript with Google's Chart API described here:

[Dynamic icons](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/dynamic_icons#contextual-icons-dynamic-markers-only)

The generating of map markers doesn't work any more since a few days. This is clearly stated at the top of the link:
"*Warning: This API is deprecated and is scheduled to be turned off on March 14, 2019. Please use the actively maintained Google Charts API instead.*"

Their link to the new Google Chart API doesn't provide any replacement for creating a map marker like icon with a custom color and a custom letter in it (what I need).

The closest I've found in the new API is:
[Customizing Markers](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/map)
But in here the only option is to replace the default Google marker with a custom image. So there seems to be no dynamic generating of markers.

Maybe I've overseen something or anyone knows a service to create google maps like markers with a letter in it and a custom color.

Answer (score 2):

In between I've found a solution that allows to set a defined color and a label inside the marker. It works without Google Chart API (Google maps API only).

The first part of the solution is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095574/google-maps-api-3-custom-marker-color-for-default-dot-marker) (see answer from vokimon):
It takes a SVG path instead of a predefined image (png). That way you can define a custom color (and even [more](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/symbols#properties) if needed):

```js
function createPin (color) {
        return {
            path: 'M 0,0 C -2,-20 -10,-22 -10,-30 A 10,10 0 1,1 10,-30 C 10,-22 2,-20 0,0 z',
            fillColor: color,
            fillOpacity: 1,
            strokeColor: '#000',
            strokeWeight: 2,
            scale: 1,
            labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(0, -30)
        };
    }
```

The "labelOrigin" is important to get the label positioned properly.

Now you can create the marker itself:

```js
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   map: <yourMapInstance>,
   position: new google.maps.LatLng(<latitude>, <longitude>),
   icon: createPin('#F6AC01'),
   label: { 
            text: 'X',
            fontWeight: 'bold'
          },
});
```

There are more nice label options if needed described [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#MarkerLabel).

Answer (score 1):

I also noticed that my icons with custom colors disappeared. There seem to be some pregenerated icons stored at http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons, such as http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png [image]

I've managed to find a list of icons hosted by Google: https://sites.google.com/site/gmapsdevelopment/

Comment: Nice list for any purpose. In my case I need to set the color but also a letter (label) inside the marker.